# How to add resources when using JSLink

Tags: 2013, jslink

I am using JSLink to change view of a custom list using this code,

```
(function () {
    var overrideCtx = {};
    overrideCtx.Templates = {};
    overrideCtx.BaseViewID = 2;
    overrideCtx.ListTemplateType = 17774;
    overrideCtx.OnPreRender = preRenderHandler17774;
    overrideCtx.OnPostRender = postRenderHandler17774;
    SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
})();
```

Both preRender and postRender functions need to get some resources from a custom file which has been added to 15 hive "Resources" folder, Now I can use this code to get resources, but I am not sure how to best get resources here,

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(function () {
  SP.SOD.registerSod("demoresources", 
    "/_layouts/15/ScriptResx.ashx?name=demoresources&culture=" + 
    STSHtmlEncode(Strings.STS.L_CurrentUICulture_Name));
 
  SP.SOD.executeFunc("demoresources", 'Res', function () {
    alert(Res.helloWorld);
  });
}, "strings.js");
```

Where is the best to place this code in above ?

> And how can I get culture in preRender method ? as this is undefinied
>   String.STS.L_CurrentUICul...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error occurs since `strings.js` file is *not yet loaded* when `OnPreRender` method is invoked.

I would recommend to consider the following script for loading Resource file:

```
function loadResourceFile(resourceKey,complete)
{
    var resourceUrl = String.format("{0}/ScriptResx.ashx?name={1}&culture={2}", _spPageContextInfo.layoutsUrl,resourceKey,_spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName);
    SP.SOD.registerSod(resourceKey, resourceUrl);
    SP.SOD.executeFunc(resourceKey, 'Res.' + resourceKey, function () {
        complete(Res);
    });
}
```

**Key points**

- It has dependency only to `init.js` from SharePoint JavaScript
  Library (it is **already** loaded when when `OnPreRender` method is invoked)
- `_spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName property` is used to determine
  the current culture

Then the following example demonstrates how to load Resource file in template:

```
SP.SOD.executeFunc("clienttemplates.js", "SPClientTemplates", function() {

      SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides({

        OnPreRender: function(ctx) {
          console.log('OnPreRender');
          loadResourceFile('MossChart',function(resdata){
             console.log('Resource file is loaded');
             console.log(resdata);
           });

        },
        OnPostRender: function(ctx) { 
           console.log('OnPostRender');
        }
      });

});
```

> In the specified example `MossChart.en-us.resx` file is loaded

Answer (score 1):

you need to use **RegisterModuleInit** this will make the CSR wait until upload the required resources.

for more info: [Register CSR-override on MDS enabled SharePoint 2013 site](http://blogs.technet.com/b/sharepointdevelopersupport/archive/2013/02/08/register-csr-override-on-mds-enabled-sharepoint-2013-site.aspx)

for culture, you can use this, _spPageContextInfo.currentCultureName